# Custom function as "edit" in Midnight Commander

Tags: midnight-commander

**The problem**

I'm using tmux and I want MC to open files for editing in another tmux window, so that I can keep browsing files while editing.

**What I've tried**

MC checks if EDITOR variable is set and then interprets it as a program for editing, so if I do `export EDITOR=vim` then MC will use vim to open files.

I've tried to build on that:

```
function foo () { tmux new-window "vim $1"; }
export EDITOR=foo
```

If I do `$EDITOR some_file` then I get the file open in vim in another tmux windows - exactly what I wanted.

Sadly, when I try to edit in MC it goes blank for a second and then returns to normal MC window. MC doesn't seem to keep any logs and I don't get any error message.

**The question(s)**

- Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
- Do you have a usable workaround for what I want?
- Should I create a feature request/bug for MC?

Comment: Create a bash script, not a function. I guess `mc` does not know about shell functions when launching editor.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, random person from the Internet! Your wisdom is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a shell function, which is unknown for `mc` when it is trying to start the editor.

The correct way is to create a bash script, not a function. Then set `EDITOR` value to it, for example:

```
$ cat ~/myEditor.sh
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-window "vim $1"

export EDITOR=~/myEditor.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can already browse files while editing. MC's internal editor is a modeless dialog box. Just press `Alt-Shift-[` (and `Alt-Shift-[`) to switch among the dialogs (one of which is the file browser).